# Changing store views doesn't apply unless I flush cache

Tags: cache, store-view

I have 2 store views. Arabic and English.  Each has it own design. The problem is that when I load a store view it shows correctly but when I changet to the other store view the page design remains the same.

The only solution us to go and flush cache manually from backend to show the correct design that correspondes to the store view.

Plz help

Answer (score 0):

It may be cause of incorrect design structure of your different store view, or if you use varnish cache than you may need configure correctly it.